# systemd rqworker service

Tags: server, systemd, services, redis, supervisor

Systemd service, I want to create but it fails.
This is my service i have created.

```
[Unit]
Description=rqworker daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/mamster
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/master.env
#Environment="PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/venv"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv /venv/bin/rqworker master
StandardOutput=/home/ubuntu/logs/icengine/std_out.log
StandardError=/home/ubuntu/logs/icengine/std_err/log
#SyslogIdentifier=icengin
KillMode=process
Restart=always
TimeoutSec=infinity
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=master.service
```

Initially this service is `Actiating(Start)` but was not `Active`

But after i made some changes and now it showing error:

After running `sudo systemctl start rq`

```
(venv) ubuntu@ubuntucalc:~$ sudo systemctl status rq
● rq.service - rqworker daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-15 06:53:20 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 18537 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv /venv/bin/rqworker master (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 18537 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: rq.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: rq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: Failed to start rqworker daemon.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: rq.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: rq.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: Stopped rqworker daemon.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: rq.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: rq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 06:53:20 ubuntucalc systemd[1]: Failed to start rqworker daemon.
```

This is the output i have got.
Thanks

Comment: What does the std_out / std_err logs say ?

Comment: @SorenA well this makes it more complicate. Even logs are also not recording.

Comment: You have two lines `Type=`. The given type must match the type of the program. For daemons, often `forking` is right but it depends on how `/home/ubuntu/venv` works.

Comment: wow! @PerlDuck Thanks for letting my attention to the `Type=` , I didn't noticed that i have two `Type` and finally i removed both beacuse i need `Type=simple`. Which is default. 
So again THANKS!
Type same in Answer and i'll approve :)

Comment: But still my Logs not generate!!!

Comment: You configured `.../std_err/log`. Shouldn't that be `.../std_err.log`?

Comment: Typing mistake!!! `std_err.log` only. But still no logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in that unit file:

- The file contains two instances of `Type=`, one 
  with `simple` and one with `notify`. It must contain
  only one such line and that must be of the proper
  type which in turn depends on how the executable
  `/home/ubuntu/venv` behaves. For daemons, often `forking`
  is used.
- The filename given for `StandardError` should presumably be
  `/home/ubuntu/logs/icengine/std_err.log` and not 
  `/home/ubuntu/logs/icengine/std_err/log`. Make sure the user
  `ubuntu` is able to write to that location and the directories
  exist. I reckon `systemd` won't create the path if it doesn't
  exist (although it'll create the *file*).
- The syntax of `StandardOutput=` and `StandardError=` is wrong.
  According to the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) the sysntax is
  `StandardOutput=file:/home/ubuntu/logs/icengine/std_out.log`.
  Same for `StandardError`.

Comment: I was looking at it and just now i realised that for `StandardError=file:/path/` it won't work there are some additional need to specify some `inherit` thing, I didn't know how it works???

`StandardOutput=file:/home/ubuntu/logs/master_std_out.log`
`StandardError=file:/home/ubuntu/logs/master_std_err.log`